# Knockout Bindings Deep Level Context

Tags: jquery, html, mvvm, knockout.js

I have this table:

```
<div data-bind="with: viewModel">
<table class="displayTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Packs</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: productJson">
        <tr>
            <th data-bind="text: code"></th>
            <th data-bind="text: name"></th>
            <th>
                <table class="innerTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Colour</td>
                            <td>MOQ</td>
                            <td>Volume</td>
                            <td>Price</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: packs">
                        <tr>
                            <td data-bind="text: color"></td>
                            <td data-bind="text: moq"></td>
                            <td data-bind="text: volume"></td>
                            <td data-bind="text: price"></td>
                            <td>
                                <button data-bind="click: $context.addProduct">Add</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

It has its context: `viewModel`, then there is an embedded `foreach` which changes the context for everything inside, then there is an embedded `foreach` within that `foreach` context, changing the context once again.

What I need to do is access the `viewModel` context from within the most embedded `foreach` where there is a button with its click event binded to `addProduct`.

How do you get the `addProduct` to be refenced to the `viewModel` context. `$parent` doesn't do it, neither does `$parents[2 or 1 or 0]`.

See [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/aHtU8/)

Comment: Why is your `viewModel` is a function in your jsfiddle? It confuses the `with` binding... without the `with` binding and using `ko.applyBindings(new mainClass.viewModel());` it works... http://jsfiddle.net/cqj4c/

Comment: @nemesv yeah I done that, and it works fine. However, if I were to have multiple viewModels, I will need to know which viewModels I'm working with, and I usually group them together in a `var mainClass = { viewModel1: function () {}, viewModel2: function () {} }`

Comment: ok but if you are using const functions you need to create instances. with `new viewmodel1` and `new viewModel2` otherwise KO will be confused and won't work correctly like in your fiddle. So you need something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/89wQw/

Comment: that is genius!!! Do you want to write a quick proper answer and I'll upvote nd accept it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using functions in your view model properties and this confuses KO.

The proper solution would be to move out your view model creation functions in their own place and build up your `mainClass` with using the now the view model instances created by your view model functions:

```
var ViewModelDefinition =  function () {
    //...
}

var mainClass = {
    viewModel: new ViewModelDefinition()
}

ko.applyBindings(mainClass);
```

And in your view in need to reference your handler with `$root.viewModel.addProduct` because it can be found under the `viewModel`:

```
 <button data-bind="click: $root.viewModel.addProduct">Add</button>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89wQw/).

Comment: how do you get the index of the parent `foreach` loop when inside the most embedded `foreach`

Comment: You need to use `$parentContext.$index` where $parentContext

This refers to the binding context object at the parent level. This is different from $parent, which refers to the data (not binding context) at the parent level. see  http://jsfiddle.net/abH8m/